# Python function that parses a long string as key-value pairs for logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I noticed I tend to use many if-conditions in my code, and I know there is a way to simplify this with one-liners.

The function is iterating through configuration dictionaries so that I can log parameters in MLflow not as a long non-readable string:

[image: before]

but as key-value pairs:

[image: after]

```
!pip install mlflow
!python -m pip install -e detectron2


import mlflow
import detectron2
from detectron2.config import get_cfg, CfgNode

cfg = get_cfg()

for k, v in cfg.items():
                # (1) check if params are being logged as a long hard-to-read string
                if type(v) == detectron2.config.config.CfgNode:
                    
                # (1) if yes, iterate through it to log separately
                for kk, vv in v.items():
                    # (2) check again if params are being logged as a long hard-to-read string
                    if type(vv) == detectron2.config.config.CfgNode:

                        # (2) if yes, iterate through it to log separately
                        for kkk, vvv in vv.items():
                            # (3) check again if params are being logged as a long hard-to-read string
                            if type(vvv) == detectron2.config.config.CfgNode:
                                
                                # (3) if yes, iterate through it to log separately
                                for kkkk, vvvv in vvv.items():
                                    
                                    # (3) generate param_name
                                    param_name = k + '.' + kk + '.' + kkk + '.' + kkkk
                                    print(param_name, ':', vvvv)
                                    
                                    # (3) log if exists
                                    if vvvv:
                                        mlflow.log_param(param_name, vvvv)
                            
                            # (3) if not a dict
                            else:
                                # (3) generate param_name
                                param_name = k + '.' + kk + '.' + kkk
                                print(param_name, ':', vvv)

                                # (3) log if variable exists
                                if vvv:
                                    mlflow.log_param(param_name, vvv)

                    # (2) if not a dict  
                    else:
                        # (2) generate param_name
                        param_name = k + '.' + kk
                        print(param_name, ':', vv)
                        
                        # (2) log if exists
                        if vv:
                            mlflow.log_param(param_name, vv)
                            

            # (1) if not a dict            
            else:
                print(k, ':', v)
                
                # (1) log if exists
                if v:
                    mlflow.log_param(k, v)
```

I would gladly provide you with more details if necessary. Thanks in advance for all the tips and suggestions!

Comment: Code Review needs code that can be run by reviewers, can you give an example input and output so it's executable by reviewers?

Comment: @lukstru added input, output is in the photo

Comment: Also could you give your variables some names that have some meaning too please or use _ if they're not needed. It looks like a function could be useful, but it's tricky to read with all those single or double letters eg use: *node* or *log_item* or *error_log_item_list*. I'm just making up some names but I'm sure you get the drift. Or _

Comment: @Lozminda thanks for the input. in my case, k = key and v = value, I thought such notation was standard while iterating through a dictionary. I admit that kkkk and vvvv are not as obvious, but also had no idea what naming would be better. giving a name like k_dict_num_3 seems redundant to me. but I would love to hear any name suggestions, that make the code more readable in my case

Comment: @Kami You know what you're looking at having worked on it for a day/week/month. The folks at code review are giving their time for nothing, so anything you can do to make our lives a bit easier, the better. After looking through everything you've posted (for 15-20 mins) I now kinda see what you're trying to achieve. My question is: Can what you call all your varaibles help reduce that time ? Maybe the answer is no ? Maybe yes. Re conventions they're always debated. Will explore more deeply if I have time later. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are basically trying to "flatten" a nested dict. A recursive generator works nicely. For each key,value pair in the dict, make a recursive call if the value is a dict, otherwise yield the key,value pair (the base case).

Note: you shouldn't use `type(cfg) == some_class`. Use `isinstance()` instead.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

def flatten_cfg(cfg, keys=''):
    
    for key, value in cfg.items():
        new_keys = f"{keys}.{key}" if keys else key

        if isinstance(value, Mapping):
            yield from flatten_cfg(value, new_keys)

        else:
            yield (new_keys, value)
```

Use it like so:

```
cfg = {
    "ANCHOR":{
        "GENERATOR":{
            "ANGLES":[[-90, 0, 90]],
            "ASPECT_RATIOS":[[0,5, 1.0, 2.0]],
            "NAME":"DefaultAnchorGenerator",
            "SIZES":[[32], [64], [128], [256], [512]]
        }
    },
    "AUG":{
        "FLIP":True,
        "MAX_SIZE":4000,
        "MIN_SIZES":(400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200)
    },
    "BACKBONE":{
        "FREEZE_AT":2,
        "NAME":"build_resnet_fpn_backbone"
    }
}

flat_cfg = list(flatten_cfg(cfg))

width = max(len(name) for name,_ in flat_cfg)
for name, value in flat_cfg:
    print(f"{name:{width}s}  {value}")
```

Output:

```
ANCHOR.GENERATOR.ANGLES         [[-90, 0, 90]]
ANCHOR.GENERATOR.ASPECT_RATIOS  [[0, 5, 1.0, 2.0]]
ANCHOR.GENERATOR.NAME           DefaultAnchorGenerator
ANCHOR.GENERATOR.SIZES          [[32], [64], [128], [256], [512]]
AUG.FLIP                        True
AUG.MAX_SIZE                    4000
AUG.MIN_SIZES                   (400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200)
BACKBONE.FREEZE_AT              2
BACKBONE.NAME                   build_resnet_fpn_backbone
```

Comment: just tested your code, does the same as mine, but much cleaner! thank you so much! I knew I could extract the functionality of the same if-else-conditions, but wasn't sure how. I've never used yield, but now I know how. and also great isinstance() tip!

Answer (score 3):

> I noticed I tend to use many if-conditions in my code

Conditionals are not necessarily bad, and code can contain lots of them. They are however hard to reason about when they're nested. However, you have made your work to fix them easier for yourself by adding convenient comments:

> `# (1) if yes, iterate through it to log separately`

These comments describe what the block below does, and provide good indicators for code that can be extracted, and usually provide a good name as well.
If you use Jetbrains products like IntelliJ, the IDE can do most of the work for you: mark the block to be extracted -> right click -> Refactor -> Extract. If not, [refactoring.guru/extract-method](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method) has a neat example and explanation.

You also have quite a few imbalanced conditionals in the style of

```py
if condition:
    doSomethingRegular()
else:
    edgeCase()
```

This is a prime example of code that can be refactored into a guard statement:

```
if not condition:
    return edgeCase()

return doSomethingRegular()
```

`return` can of course be replaced with continue or break, whatever is needed. Usually, you want to extract the inner blocks though and then it ends up as a return statement anyways. For more info, https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses is a good resource.

[My recent post about making code more readable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10812/how-do-i-make-my-code-more-readable) is also a good resource if you want to go a bit more in depth.